# How to select a section of a raster in R using a search window?

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, terra

I want to select a group of pixels from a raster.

- The user should enter an *n* value for selecting the number of columns and rows (or window size).
- A window would fetch the number of pixels defined.
- Would return a raster with the values.

Below is a piece of reproducible example:

```
library(terra)
r <- terra::set.ext(rast(volcano), terra::ext(0, nrow(volcano), 0, ncol(volcano)))
plot(r)
```

The idea is to start from the upper/left size using, i.e., 10 pixels for rows and cols (100 pixels as total) as a box window search.

For this I thought to get the min and max extent (using *terra* package) as the code below:

```
w_10 <- c(xmin(terra::ext(r)),xmin(terra::ext(r))+10,ymin(terra::ext(r)),ymin(terra::ext(r))+10)
```

After I imagine some iterations, the window search will go through all the raster lengths and should return pieces of rasters.

After all, the objective is to get different groups of pieces raster sizes, as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Hugo Machado Rodrigues, not sure to fully understand but I guess you might be looking for the `terra::focal()` or `terra::focalMat()` function. Hope this will help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard indexing

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

w10 <- r[1:10, 1:10, drop=FALSE]
```

Or use `crop`

```
xmin <- xmin(r)
ymax <- ymax(r)
rs <- res(r)

n <- 10
xmax <- xmin + n * rs[1] 
ymin <- ymax - n * rs[2]

x <- crop(r, c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to iterate through all the raster and save temporary (as objects, variables, list, data.table, data.frame) each piece of these cropped rasters?

Comment: Look at @lovalery 's suggestion above `terra::focal`, `terra::focalMat`, then also consider maybe `draw` as you might not always want your users to start in top left corner, but essentially 'give me a window around this point'...interactively. And ask another question.